# Duplicate node in keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

```css
from keras import backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Layer, Add, Multiply
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
original_dim = 784

inputs = Input(shape=(original_dim,))
x = Dense(e_dim1, activation='relu')(inputs)

eps1 = Input(tensor=K.random_normal(stddev=1.0,shape=(K.shape(x)[0], latent_dim)))
eps2 = Input(tensor=K.random_normal(stddev=1.0,shape=(K.shape(x)[0], latent_dim)))
```

In the example above, I try to sample from a latent dimension for further use in a Keras model. When I run the second sampling, i.e. eps I get the following error.

```css
ValueError: Duplicate node name in graph: 'random_normal/shape'
```

It might be that the error is specific to tensorflow 2.0, as python doesn't throw an error on tensorflow==1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this function before, because somehow the graph can't calculate the dimension of the tensor through random_normal, so I tried to specify input_shape or output_Shape, and it worked, so I strongly recommend that you do the same